# How to extend IdentityUserLogin in ASP.NET Identity model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I want to extend the default functionality and for integration with social networks I want to store profile's avatar Url as well. I think it would be reasonable to extend `IdentityUserLogin` class that stores information about the integration but can't find any information how to do that.

Am I on the right way or it's bad idea and better to use some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just update the model that the default MVC5 project creates for you (or create a new one if you need):

```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
   {
      public string HomeTown { get; set; }
      public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
   }
```

The DB context then gets updated as such:

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
   {
      public ApplicationDbContext()
         : base("DefaultConnection")
      {
      }
   }
```

And now, in your controller, you'll have access to the additional properties that you've added.

Comment: Hi Brendan, I saw a lot of examples how to extent IdentityUser functionality and I don't think that it will be right to use the same in my case. Do you suggest to add some Avatar URL to the ApplicationUser class? If yes, it won't work...

Comment: Why won't it work?  You just updated the callback method on the account controller to extract the avatar URL and update the user.

Comment: It won't work in terms of general architecture... one user account can be integrated with several social network providers and it would be good to store avatar urls for all of them. And storing this information in AspNetUserLogins table would me more logical. And this was my question - how to add additional information to this table.